# Routing changes when upgrading easyadmin bundle symfony

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I am in charge of upgrading easyadmin bundle on an app that was previously built using symfony v4.4.19. Initially we had: easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v2.3.12. Then, we decided to upgrade the easyadmin bundle to v3 because we faced some issues when enabling/disabling a boolean property from the list view.

When I was using the v2 :

- php bin/console debug:router showed a route called easyadmin with a path /myworkshop/ .
- I had no Dashboard controller nor NecklaceCrudController, I simply had a controlller called
  AccessoriesController.php with several actions like deleteAction that is executed when the user
  deletes an entity, editAction when the user edits an entity, SearchAction ...
  In the deleteAction there is this line of code:

  `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('easyadmin', array('action' => 'list', 'entity'=> $this->entity['name'])));`

  so the url would become something like this
  /myworkshop/?action=list&entity=necklace
- To open the easy admin interface I have to click on a menu link whose link is :
  `->createItem('Visit my workshop', ['route' => 'easyadmin']);`
- When I open this interface /references, I get the list of the different entities in my app, if
  I select  one, I see the list view  and I can edit one entity successfully but I cannot
  enable/disable boolean properties from the list view as mentioned earlier.
- We specified /myworkshop instead of /admin in app>config>routing.yml

````
# easy admin
easy_admin_bundle:
    resource: "@myShop/Controller/AccessoriesController.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /myworkshop```


 - A custom css was successfully employed in : app>config>config.yml
    easy_admin:
    design:
        assets:
            css:
                - 'bundles/css/easyadmin.css
````

When I upgraded to v3:

- php bin/console debug:router showed a route called myshop_admin_dashboard_index (which was
  automatically generated) with a path /easyadmin.
- Dashboard controller and NecklaceCrudController were created, The DashboardController only has configureCrud() and configureMenuItems() functions. The latter contains the links  `yield MenuItem::linkToCrud` . Question 1 : In version 2 no menu links where created explicitely like here, so I was wondering how was the complete list of entities correctly showing up on my application interface?
- In DashboardController there is no index () function nor a route nor a link just configureCrud() and configureMenuItems() functions.
- I want to keep the AccessoriesController.php with his several actions but now, with the new route and path, it is completely being ignored. Question 2 : Is there something that I have to change in the generateUrl part? can someone give me an example of what this will become if I opt for adminUrlgenerator like I read in the documentation?
- The routing.yml file remains the same however, my easyadmin interface appears only when visiting this link /easyadmin instead of /myworkshop . Question 3: I want to keep the /workshop url , what should I do in addition to keeping the routing.yml as it is now?
  I wish we could change myshop_admin_dashboard_index  to easyadmin and /easyadmin to my /myworkshop as it was in version 2, because there are many parts in AccessoriesController where I use `$this->generateUrl('easyadmin',`
- Question 4: The css is no longer applicable any idea why? could be related to the AccessoriesController  that is not currently being taken into account.

Comment: Please do not post multiple different problem statements within a single question

Comment: Also, which parts of the upgrade notes did you read and apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can add the `index` method to your dashboard controller with route annotation to change the route

```
class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/myworkshop", name="admin")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('dashboard/index.html.twig');
    }
```

You can add any route to easyadmin menu like this

```
class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::linktoRoute('Some Route', 'fa fa-info', 'route_name_here');
        #...
    }
}
```

You can add any CSS/js file too

```
class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{
    public function configureAssets(): Assets
    {
        return Assets::new()
            ->addCssFile('build/admin.css')
            ->addJsFile('build/admin.js')
            ;
    }
}
```